# Google Admin Analytics API Python error: Unknownapiversionorname

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the google analytics API to automate property creation on python. It was working initially for a day, but now I'm getting this error:

UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: analyticsadmin  version: v1beta

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secrets.json'
#VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsadmin', 'v1beta', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics
```

I'm getting an error when I call this function

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'v1alpha' instead of 'v1beta'. That should do the trick.

Comment: Figured the whole thing out!